# How to compare sizes of two uncountably infinite sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know the set of real numbers is uncountably infinite. Is there a way to determine which of two uncountably infinite sets is larger ? For example how do I go about deciding whether $\mathbb{R}$ is larger or set of functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ larger ?

Comment: [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem) together with the fact that there are at least as many functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ as there are functions $\mathbb{R} \to \{1,2\}$ (for which there is a clear bijection to the power set of $\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an injective function $f\colon A\to B$, and further  no function $g\colon B\to A$ can be injective, then $B$ is a *larger* set than $A$.

Comment: Similarly, if there's a surjection $B \to A$ but no surjection $A \to B$, then $B$ is strictly larger than $A$.

Comment: @BrianO: Yes, that is an equally  valid approach. There will be situations where surjectivity may be easier to settle.

Answer (score 2):

Another strategy:

If there's an injection  $A \to B$ but no surjection $A \to B$, then $B$ is strictly larger than $A$.

So: first find an injection $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$.

Now, suppose there is a surjection $F\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$. Use a diagonal construction to define an $f \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ which can't be in the range of $F$: define
$$ f(x) = F(x)(x) + 1 \quad \text{for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.}
$$